# Digital Ocean Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: python, django, apache2, digital-ocean

***I am using Django I do not know how to setup config file***
'''

1. Alias /static root/pixlfy/googlesheet/static    <Directory
   root/pixlfy/googlesheet/static>         Require all granted

   ```
   <Directory root/pixlfy/googlesheet/googlesheet>         <Files wsgi.py>
           Require all granted         </Files>    </Directory>


   WSGIDaemonProcess pixlfy python-home=root/pixlfy/projectenv
   ```

   python-path=root/pixlfy/googlesheet     WSGIProcessGroup pixlfy
   WSGIScriptAlias / root/pixlfy/googlesheet/googlesheet/wsgi.py

   ```
   <Directory root/pixlfy/googlesheet/googlesheet>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all  </Directory>
   ```

'''

Comment: Whats your os? Do you use Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04

It's recommended that you create another user with sudo rights and place your website in that user's home folder.

This way you won't have any trouble with privileges.